# How to override the default value of COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT with docker-compose command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose which fetches some of the images and builds one.
When I run `docker-compose up` , I am getting the following error

> **ERROR:** An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose
>   to obtain debug information. If you encounter this issue regularly
>   because of slow network conditions, consider setting
>   COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

**Question:** How to pass the `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT` with `docker-compose` command?

Comment: restart the docker

command: `sudo service docker restart`

then try `docker-compose up`

Comment: Please consider editing your question to make it clear that COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT is deprecated in v2 (older versions are EOL) and the env var no longer seems to have an effect. You must specify the --timeout option.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#deprecated-in-compose-v2

Answer (score 164, accepted):

`COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT` is an environment variable, so

```
COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200 docker-compose up
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

The only thing that seems to work is putting this in the .env for the directory. This is something that I am reluctant to do as a lot of other applications use the .env file by default. E.g craft cms. And I don't want docker-compose setting mixing with these application settings

Comment: We here have more configurable answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38631255/7152658

Comment: Worked great for me since I didn't need a permanent change, I was just getting stuck one time.

Answer (score 56):

You need your `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT` at your docker instance level (`docker-compose up`) and not inside your docker image. So the solution is to create a `.env` file and put this inside:

```
#.env
COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200
```

you can check the doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)

Comment: I guess, you can place the .env file at the root of your project directory, so probably next to your docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 30):

For Mac users, `restarting docker` from the status bar icon fixed this issue:

[image: Restarting Docker]

Comment: This solution worked for me. You can a confirm in this thread.
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3633

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

restart the docker

command: **sudo service docker restart**

then try docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently. Even after overriding the default `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT` value it did not work for me.

Possible cause As mentioned in documentation [Compose CLI environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/)

> COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT: Configures the time (in seconds) a request to the Docker daemon is allowed to hang before Compose considers it failed. Defaults to 60 seconds.

**Removing the `tty:true` from my docker-compose  worked for me.**

More details on the issue[Compose error "HTTP request took too long to complete" #3633](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3633)

**Docker Environment details:**

```
$ docker-compose version

docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
docker-py version: 2.6.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016



$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:35:01 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:06:30 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this one in [.env](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) file: `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=1000`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue as below:
[image]

Quick Solution is, to restart your VM

1. sudo su - root
2. reboot -f
   Then login again after 5-10 mins and check. It should work now!

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal and type following command

```
COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200
```

To verify type

```
echo $COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT
```

Output: 200